# Bitcoin Core just deleted my 350+ GB of blockchain data?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've kept the same config file and internal hard drive for my Bitcoin Core datadir for many years. I've updated to numerous new versions.

The other day, I reinstalled Windows on the system drive again. And thus reinstalled Bitcoin Core (v22.0.0) again. When it started up, I pointed it to the datadir on the other disk as usual.

Now I realize that it has deleted all of the blockchain data for the first time ever, leaving only 2 GB. It prunes by default to 2 GB now. And apparently, my config needed to have an explicit rule to tell it to not prune... which it of course didn't.

While I'm glad that I don't have to store all that stupid data anymore, it does make me question why they would enable this by default and actually *delete* existing data. Has pruning now reached such a level of stability that it's completely "safe" and there is no need to save the full blockchain anymore?

Or am I now running Bitcoin Core in "crippled mode"? Even though I did not actively set it to prune?

Comment: Bitcoin Core will never prune on its own; it is not default. It must be configured, either through config file, command-lirn arguments, or the GUI settings window, to enable pruning.

Comment: @PieterWuille No "prune" command in my config.

Comment: Are you using `bitcoind` or `bitcoin-qt`? Have you checked the UI settings (they are separate from bitcoin.conf)? Is something about "prune" logged in debug.log?

Comment: @PieterWuille `bitcoin-qt.exe`. Yes, the UI settings were and are set to prune at 2 GB, since that's now the default, but the bitcoin.conf is supposed to take precedence over the GUI settings.

Comment: I thought GUI settings override bitcoin.conf, but I'm not entirely sure about that. Still, pruning is *not* the default as far as I know (it's not for me, in either bitcoind or bitcoin-qt, and I don't have any pruning related settings anywhere).

Comment: @PieterWuille I don't know what to tell you. I have certainly not set up pruning in the GUI.

Comment: I also don't know what to tell you, except that no, pruning is not on by default.

Comment: @PieterWuille So I have a magical or compromised copy of Bitcoin Core, then?

Comment: It appears I'm wrong. The "first run" dialog, when selecting a filesystem with less than a certain threshold available space, will suggest have pruning enabled by default. If you then click continue without turning it off, that becomes the saved GUI setting for Bitcoin-Qt.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and happened with me once: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui/issues/245

Pieter Wuille's last comment summarizes the issue:

> The "first run" dialog, when selecting a filesystem with less than a certain threshold available space, will suggest have pruning enabled by default. If you then click continue without turning it off, that becomes the saved GUI setting for Bitcoin-Qt.

It would be resolved by a [pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/15936) in which settings for `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-qt` are unified. It can be helpful if you review, test and comment in the pull request as its lacking review and open since 2019.